# How to get website content from QWebEnginePage?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine, qt5.6

I installed the newest version of Qt (on Webkit, Qt5.2 had WTFcrash). I try to get content of my website when the page is loaded (and it is):

```
QString sHtml;
view.page()->toHtml([&](const QString& result){sHtml = result;qDebug() << result;});
```

But `sHtml` is empty, and debug not called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, `toPlainText` work properly. Still don't know why toHtml doesn't.

Comment: Probably because `sHtml` went out of scope by the time `toHtml` was invoked.

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything wrong, you're just calling an asynchronous [function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#toHtml) :

> Asynchronous method to retrieve the page's content as HTML, enclosed
>   in HTML and BODY tags. Upon successful completion, resultCallback is
>   called with the page's content.

The HTML won't be available directly after the call to `toHtml()`. Instead, you can use some signals and slots to overcome this :

```
protected slots:
    void handleHTML(QString sHTML);

signals:
    void getHTML(QString sHTML);

 void yourClass::yourFunction()
 {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(getHTML(QString)), this, SLOT(handleHTML(QString)));
    view->page()->toHtml([this](const QString& result) mutable {emit getHTML(result);});
 }

void yourClass::handleHTML(QString sHTML)
{
      qDebug()<< "The HTML is :" << sHTML;
}
```